# Meaning of the Eigenvalues of the Hessian Matrix in Polar Coordinates in a Ferromagnetic System

Tags: hamiltonian, eigenvalue, magnetostatics, ferromagnetism

I have the Hamiltonian for a magnetostatic system (exchange, dipole-dipole, zeeman) which is in polar coordinates since the spins are confined to being in-plane. If I calculate the Hessian Matrix of this Hamiltonian and diagonalize it, I get eigenvalues with units of energy.

If we were to look at just the Zeeman energy for a 2x2 spin system, taking the second derivatives gives us μ * B Cos (θ<sub>a,b</sub> - θ<sub>H</sub>) where θ<sub>H</sub> is the angle of the applied field, which are the diagonal terms of the Hessian. Since this matrix has no off-diagonal terms (due to no interaction term), these end up being the eigenvalues. We thus have 4 eigenvalues with four eigenmodes of form (1, 0, 0, 0) and so on. If I were to put in some starting state of spin angles, I would thus get the energy of each of the eigenmodes e.g. μ B Cos (π/2 - π/4)

If I were to add in the exchange and dipole-dipole interaction terms, I would have a Hessian matrix with off-diagonal terms. If I were to diagonalize this matrix, would it still be true that the resultant eigenvalues would be the energies of the resultant eigenmodes for a given starting spin state?

I understand that if I were taking the Hessian derivatives with respect to some spatial coordinates e.g. x, y, z, I would get something more akin to a spring constant which would allow me to get the energies of the modes by using some effective mass of the eigenmodes.